# Given that 5 sixes are obtained from 20 rolls, find the probability that the 2nd six was rolled on the 6th roll.

Tags: probability

Given that 5 sixes are obtained from 20 rolls, find the probability that the 2nd six was rolled on the 6th roll?

In the context of a fair six sided die.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: find the number of ways to roll 20 times, get a single six on the first 5 rolls, get a six on the sixth roll, and get 3 sixes on the last 14 rolls.

Comment: This way of counting makes counts the number of ways the sixth roll contains the second 6.

Comment: You are right.  I missed the fact that the six on the sixth roll had to be second.  +1